# Magento - cannot use guest checkout, error in opcheckout.js

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to use the Guest checkout on Magento 1.7, for some reason when I attempt to use guest checkout option I get the following error (the page doesn't change)

```
// on line 114
TypeError: sectionElement is null  
sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
```

that actual block in that js files looks like as follows:

```
gotoSection: function(section)
{
   var sectionElement = $('opc-'+section);
   sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
   this.accordion.openSection('opc-'+section);
   this.reloadProgressBlock(section);
}
```

Can anyone suggest any reason for the error - our theme has been modified recently obviously however I am sure where is best to check to debug this problem.

UPDATE:
Having used the debugger tools in Firefox I can see within this function the section variable is set to 'org' - this page has since been removed and will no longer be required within the checkout process. Can anyone suggest where this 'org' value is being set in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - for anyone else that may find this useful I had references as follows within the opcheckout.js

```
this.gotoSection('org');
```

As this section had been removed it needed to be removed from the same js file.. magento never simple :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that 'opcheckout.js' is looking for the element 'opc' and it cannot be found for the guest checkout steps. I would first check the file:

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/checkout/onepage.phtml
```

as a starting point to troubleshoot the problem.

Double check you do not have any extensions, modules, etc. conflicting with your checkout process.

You can enable System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints, set to Yes and Add Block Names to Hints, set to Yes. This will help you identify which module/block is outputting the code block which is incorrect on the checkout page. If you can identify the main content area template path, you can then inspect the template file using FTP.

Try disabling modules in the System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output > Disable any Modules which may be in conflict, flush magento caches and retest guest checkout.